# How do erase the contents of a error.log file but keep the file intact

Tags: ubuntu, logging, nginx

I want to erase the contents of the file error.log (nginx error log file), but I don't want to actually delete the file.

is this possible?

running ubuntu

Answer (score 74):

You can use this:

```
>error.log
```

(typed just like that - an empty output redirection)

or

```
truncate -s0 error.log
```

Comment: @Ignacio: If the file already exists, either will truncate it. If the file doesn't exist, either will create it.

Comment: You're right, my bad.

Comment: The last option worked for me, for some reason sudo >error.log didnt work for me (ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: @davidkonrad: You would have to already be root for the redirection to work since it's performed before `sudo` takes effect. Or you can do `sudo bash -c '>error.log'`

Comment: OK, didnt knew that. Thank you for clarification!

Comment: The first one worked for me perfectly! Even though I dont understand what it does :D Thank you

Comment: @divHelper11: In my answer I say it's an "empty output redirection". That means that "nothing" is being sent to the named file and that overwrites any existing contents. It's similar to `echo "some words" > output.txt` but nothing is going in.

Answer (score 2):

You'll confuse the daemon. Erase the file then send `SIGHUP` to nginx.

Comment: SIGHUP?  Can't I shut nginx down, purge the file, then start?  I want to know how to erase the file for knowledge sake also.

Comment: If you wanted to, sure. But that would disrupt service.

Comment: I think both a null redirection and a `truncate` are atomic, so as long as no seeking is going on (especially if the only operation that's occurring is appending) it shouldn't be disruptive.